# Add more text fields dynamically in new line (html)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I used code from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/ html-javascript/ .my code is this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Dynamically add Textbox, Radio, Button in html Form using JavaScript</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add() {

    for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
      {
        //Create an input type dynamically.
        var element = document.createElement("input");
     
        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        element.setAttribute("type", i);
        element.setAttribute("name", i);
        element.setAttribute("value", i);
     
     
        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");
     
        //Append the element in page (in span).
        foo.appendChild(element);
      }

 
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM>
<H2>Dynamically add element in form.</H2>
Select the element and hit Add to add it in form.
<BR/>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
     
<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>
     
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

That code works. But instead of adding it horizontally, I want every new text field added in a new line. I've tried to use `</script><br/><script>`, `<html><br/></html>`, `document.write("\n")`, and `document.write("\r\n")` in the loop function but it doesnt work like what I want. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
foo.appendChild(br);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the display style of the inputs.

```
function add() {

    for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
      {
        //Create an input type dynamically.
        var element = document.createElement("input");

        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        element.setAttribute("type", i);
        element.setAttribute("name", i);
        element.setAttribute("value", i);
        element.style.display = "block";

        var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

        //Append the element in page (in span).
        foo.appendChild(element);
      }
}
```

Good Luck!
I recommend you start using jQuery for your javascript tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try, adding a new br element after input element.

```
  for (i=1; i<=5; i++)
  {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");

    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", i);
    element.setAttribute("name", i);
    element.setAttribute("value", i);

    var brElement = document.createElement("br");

    var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

    //Append the element in page (in span).
    foo.appendChild(element);
    foo.appendChild(brElement );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add this to your css

```
input{display:block;}
```