# Create unique name for <input> in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Okay, first thing, I had a lot of trouble thinking of a title for this, and also of what to search for in Google. So that may just be me being stupid, but here is what I would like you help with.

I have a form, that has a button that will add additional input fields, but I would like the the name of the field to iterate everytime the button is pressed. E.g. the first time it will be:

```
<input type="textfield" name="field1" value=""/>
```

Then the second time it is pressed, it will be:

```
<input type="textfield" name="field2" value=""/>
```

I also have a small example of what I currently have here: http://jsfiddle.net/5gh75/14/

Please let me know if you can help me, or if you require more info thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to name them all `field[]`.

When handled by the server-side code, it will build an array for you. For instance, in PHP you would get `$_POST['field'][0]`, `$_POST['field'][1]` and so on.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks so much for the quick and easy answer :)

Answer (score 2):

For your example:

**JQuery**

```
var i=0;
$('span.add').click(function () {
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'textfield',
        name: 'program'+i
    }).appendTo('#addsoftware');
    i++;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gh75/17/).

But @Kolink-s answer is much better.

Comment: This is how I was about answer this question: `name: 'program'+$('input').length`

Comment: I had originally tried this, but everytime I pressed the button, the name would just be the same as the previous field :/

Comment: @Melloorr it depends where did you put the `var i=0;`. Outside or inside the `.click()` event ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just saw the previous posts after sending this. Using an array would definitely be better, and JQuery is always nice :).

Just use some javascript:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Dynamically add Textbox, Radio, Button in html Form using JavaScript</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
idx = 0;
function add() {
     //Create an input type dynamically.
     var element = document.createElement("input");

     //Assign different attributes to the element.
     element.setAttribute("type", "textfield");
     element.setAttribute("name", "field" . idx);
     element.setAttribute("value", "");

     idx++;

     var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

     //Append the element in page (in span).
     foo.appendChild(element);
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM>
<H2>Dynamically add element in form.</H2>
Select the element and hit Add to add it in form.
<BR/>
<INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>

<span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>

</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I took this example from: [Add more text fields dynamically in new line (html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224823/add-more-text-fields-dynamically-in-new-line-html)